# Is there a python type annotation for iterables that are not consumeable?

Tags: python, types

Something with similar meaning to:

```py
def func(arg: Union[List[Any], Tuple[Any]]):
    ...
```

The type would apply to any iterable that cannot be consumed, while explicitly excluding e.g. generator expressions. Example usage would be:

```py
def func(arg: NonConsumableIterable[Any]):
    ...
```

If this type exists and I have overlooked it, awesome. But if it does not exist, I would be interested to understand why it doesn't.

Comment: It'd be handy, but nope.

Comment: The `typing.Sequence` annotation is pretty close. I answered my own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type annotation `Sequence` is probably the annotation you are looking for. Note that **a sequence is not the same as a non-consumable iterable**, as noted in a comment. However, if you want your iterable to not be consumable, it is highly probable that you also want the argument to support `len` and `__getitem__`.

From the [mypy docs](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/cheat_sheet_py3.html#standard-duck-types):

> Use `Iterable` for generic iterables (anything usable in `for`),
>   and `Sequence` where a sequence (supporting `len` and `__getitem__`) is
>   required.

A [sequence](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-sequence) is defined in the python glossary as well.

So, to answer the follow-up part of the question, the likely reason why an annotation for a non-consumable iterable does not exist in the core library is because it is not a very common use case. Nevertheless, if you need really one, you can implement it with [generics](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#user-defined-generic-types)

Comment: This is wrong. For example, a dict is a non-consumable iterable, but not a sequence.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica how about now?